# Postgresql Exclude constraint on a set of values

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have a table with two columns:

```
| id | status |
```

Status can take 3 values: booked, started, completed

I need a constraint that will satisfy the following requirement:

*For entire set of rows, only one record can be in non completed state: booked or started.*

I believe I need an Exclude constraint for that, but I don't know what operator can be specified:

```sql
add constraint constraint_x   exclude (status with ANY?) 
   where  (status <> 'Completed')
```

That's the solution I came up to:

```
add constraint constraint_x exclude ((1) with =) where ((status) <> 'Completed')
```

Is this a good one?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is ok.

I would solve that with a partial unique index like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON table_name ((1)) WHERE status <> 'Completed';
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the solution I came up to:

```
add constraint constraint_x exclude ((1) with =) where ((status) <> 'Completed')
```